# jQuery datepicker style goes broken on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a style issue with jQuery UI datepicker. I was looking for the solution on Stack on this issue but still no luck. On desktop the datepicker looks nice but when I shrink the browser window to the size of mobile device it goes broken (and on my smartphone it is broken as well). I tried this datepicker here: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and it works fine for small screens so there must be something wrong with my webpage. As the code for website is messy and complicated I do not provide it but if anyone could give my a piece of advice what could be resulting in such behavior it would be very helpful (BTW the tables goes broken as well so there must a global problem with styling). Any hint appreciated. Here is the ilustration of my problem:

Correct style for desktop browser:

[image: Correct datepicker style for desktop browser]

Broken style for mobile browsers:

[image: Broken style for mobile browsers]

Comment: This is hard to answer without any code or sample. If you are familiar with css, I can suggest you inspect the elements on small screen browser to see if you find any wiered `@media` query or wrong styling. Let us know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by getting rid of some buggy code in the css of the template which was responsible for responsiveness (template was prepared by an exterior company so they must have done some mistakes here).

Answer (score 0):

use 
your phone browser must understand the field to be a HTML5 date field. For good visualization you can use